# how to query this date format in moongose and moongodb "ticketTimeStartDate": "Mon Oct 18 2021 12:28:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, mongoose

how to query this date format in moongose and moongodb
"ticketTimeStartDate": "Mon Oct 18 2021 12:28:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",

Answer (score 0):

How to generate date time format same as `Mon Oct 18 2021 12:28:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)`. I don't know how to generate it include `(Coordinated Universal Time)` at the end?